# Hibernate: get existing subcriteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have this code:

```
 Disjunction d = Restrictions.disjunction();
 ... // d is set up here
 criteria.createCriteria(linkedEntityVariable).add(d);
```

It may run twice with same value in `linkedEntityVariable`. If it happens, I get:

> duplicate association path:
>   identityCards\norg.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.createAssociationPathCriteriaMap(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:171)

How can I get my subcriteria instead of trying to create it second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of subcriteria is stored in `Criteria`'s private field. It can be read using `FieldUtils` from Apache Commons Lang 3. From `Subcriteria`, path can be read with `getPath()`.

So I've achieved what I needed with this code:

```
Disjunction d = Restrictions.disjunction();
... // d is set up here
Criteria linkedEntitySubcriteria = null;
try {
    List<CriteriaImpl.Subcriteria> subcriteriaList =
            (ArrayList) FieldUtils.readField(criteria, "subcriteriaList", true);
    for (CriteriaImpl.Subcriteria subcriteria : subcriteriaList) {
        if (subcriteria.getPath().equals(linkedEntityVariable)) {
            linkedEntitySubcriteria = subcriteria;
            break;
        }
    }
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    System.out.println("Can't get subcriteria");
}
if (linkedEntitySubcriteria == null) {
    linkedEntitySubcriteria = criteria.createCriteria(linkedEntityVariable);
}
linkedEntitySubcriteria.add(d);
```